# PHP search keyword

Tags: php, mysql, search

I have a problem. is there anyway to search a key word in my PHP program. Example if in the database There is a Full name Joe smith. And if i search Joe only it will not appear?? But if i search Joe Smith exact it will apear. i want to see all the names that have a smith in it. but its not showing it

```
<?php
session_start();

if($_SESSION['username'])
{

//Include the connection file
include "connection.php";

$sql = "SELECT * FROM users ";

if (isset($_POST['search'])) {

$search_term = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['search_box']);

$sql .= "WHERE fullname = '{$search_term}' ";

$sql .= " OR username = '{$search_term}' ";

$sql .= " OR address = '{$search_term}' ";

$sql .= " OR id = '{$search_term}' ";


}

$query = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());

echo '<FORM METHOD="LINK" ACTION="member.php">
<INPUT TYPE="submit" VALUE="Back">
</FORM>';
echo '<FORM METHOD="LINK" ACTION="display_data.php">
<INPUT TYPE="submit" VALUE="Refresh">
</FORM>';

}
else
{
die("You must be logged in!");
}

?>
<form name="search_form" method="POST" action="display_data.php">
Search: <input type='text' name='search_box' value='' />
<input type='submit' name='search' value='Search'>
</form>


<input type="button" onclick="printDiv('printableArea')" value="Print" />

<div id="printableArea">
<table width="70%" cellpadding="5" cellspace="5">

<tr>
    <td><strong>ID</strong></td>
    <td><strong>Fullname</strong></td>
    <td><strong>Username</strong></td>
    <td><strong>Address</strong></td>
</tr>
<?php while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) { ?>
<tr>
    <td><?php echo $row['id']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['fullname']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['username']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['address']; ?></td>
</tr>

<?php }?>
</div>


</table>

<script>
function printDiv(divName) {
 var printContents = document.getElementById(divName).innerHTML;
 var originalContents = document.body.innerHTML;

 document.body.innerHTML = printContents;

 window.print();

 document.body.innerHTML = originalContents;
}
</script>
```

sorry im really not GReat in english but try to understand this Sentences.

can i also ask on how to print the printable AREA with Logi in it? Tnx :))))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you may try `LIKE` instead of `=`.

Example;

```
SELECT aut_name, country FROM author WHERE aut_name LIKE 'W%';
```

and in your code

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM users ";

if (isset($_POST['search'])) {

$search_term = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['search_box']);

$sql .= "WHERE fullname LIKE '%{$search_term}%' ";

$sql .= " OR username LIKE '%{$search_term}%' ";

$sql .= " OR address LIKE '%{$search_term}%' ";

$sql .= " OR id LIKE '%{$search_term}%' ";
```

Comment: Wrap `%` in quotes `'`, you've wrapped quotes `'` with `%`